# Why does my Python program stop working and starts using 100% CPU?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, bottle

I'm having a weird issue with a Python program which is running on a Raspberry Pi. To program is supposed to receive a webhook and then execute some code which is supposed to control a cheap LED-Strip.
The program starts fine and executes fine but if I leave it running for a while and then trigger the webhook the program breaks and starts using 100% on a single CPU core. This happens both on my PC in PyCharm and on the Raspberry Pi. The thing that really throws me off is that the 'prints()' do get executed but not the rest.

```
import time
import datetime
import magichue
from bottle import route, run

light = magichue.Light('192.168.1.36')


def flash(r, g, b):
    light.mode = magichue.NORMAL
    light.rgb = (0, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    light.rgb = (r, g, b)
    time.sleep(0.4)
    light.rgb = (0, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    light.rgb = (r, g, b)
    time.sleep(0.4)


def fadein(r, g, b, tr=1):
    light.mode = magichue.NORMAL
    while tr <= 25:
        r = r + 10
        g = g + 10
        b = b + 10
        light.rgb = (r, g, b)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        tr = tr + 1
    else:
        light.rgb = (255, 255, 255)


@route('/flashgreen')
def index():
    try:
        print("Im here")
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        if 10 <= x.hour <= 22:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            light.update_status()
            if light.on:
                pr = light.rgb
                flash(0, 255, 0)
                light.rgb = pr
            else:
                flash(0, 255, 0)
                light.on = False
    except:
        pass


@route('/fadein')
def index():
    try:
        print("Im here")
        fadein(0, 0, 0)
    except:
        pass


@route('/setcolor/<r>/<g>/<b>')
def index(r, g, b):
    try:
        print("Im here")
        light.mode = magichue.NORMAL
        light.rgb = (int(r), int(g), int(b))
    except:
        pass


run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4783)
```

Answer (score 0):

The print messages are printed in a situation like this,
and everything else is not executed, as you probably get an exception within the fadein function or while changing the properties of the light object. Passing on an exception is a bad programming practice in general, and should be avoided.

My guess is that the function(s) are called repeatedly from the webhook due to the behavior of the browser when you reactivate the page after some time. Best way to debug is to print the complete exception data. This should shed some light on your mystery.

Comment: Ow yeah, I only tried to pass the error in an attempt to get a error message or something. Probably should have taken that out again before posting it.

Comment: share with us the exception that you get there

Comment: On my windows machine I get:
`[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`
On my Raspberry Pi:
`[Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: OK, so that's a major clue! The connection is probably repeatedly broken, we should focus on your webhook to see what's going on.

Comment: So do you mean look into the way I trigger the webhook or do you suggest there is a issue with the bottle library? Because I tried triggering with both a PC browser, a android browser and the android app Tasker.

Comment: To make sure it's the webhook, try running the python code in a stand alone mode, without the web side: Add a while true loop, which calls each function, with a sleep of 1sec at the end. let it run for a long period of time, and verify CPU load.

Comment: I've been running that a few hours for the last days and there aren't any problems with that.

Comment: Great! Then we have the answer to your question - and the mystery unfolds :) It must be the webhook / web page that's using it. If you feel this answers your question - please accept this answer, if not - please update your question accordingly with relevant webhook code